# Python - GUI checkbox cannot assign the function with arguments to variable

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm having trouble getting my head around assigning a function to a variable when the function uses arguments. The arguments appear to be required but no matter what arguments I enter it doesn't work.

The scenario is that I'm creating my first GUI which has been designed in QT Designer. I need the checkbox to be ticked before the accept button allows the user to continue.

Currently this is coded to let me know if ticking the checkbox returns anything (which is does) however I don't know how to pass that result onto the next function 'accept_btn'. I thought the easiest way would be to create a variable however it requires positional arguments and that's where I'm stuck.

My code:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Deleter_Main.Ui_MainWindow):
     def __init__(self):
          super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
          self.setupUi(self)
          self.ConfirmBox.stateChanged.connect(self.confirm_box)
          self.Acceptbtn.clicked.connect(self.accept_btn)

     def confirm_box(self, state):
          if self.ConfirmBox.isChecked():
               print("checked")
          else:
               print("not checked")


     checked2 = confirm_box(self, state) 


     def accept_btn(self):
          if checked2 == True:
               print("clicked")
          else:
               print("not clicked")



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MainWindow()
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

The code gets stuck on 'checked2' with the error:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

I thought there might be other solutions for running this all within one function but I can't seem to find a way whilst the below is required.

```
self.ConfirmBox.stateChanged.connect(self.confirm_box)
```

Would extra appreciate if anyone could help me understand exactly why I need the 'self' argument in the function and variable.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What is the accept button? Do you want to enable the accept button when the checkbox is verified?

Comment: The idea is the same as a Terms and Conditions page, you have to tick 'I confirm' before you can press the Next button. In my code it doesn't necessarily need to be greyed out or hidden until the checkbox is checked as I plan to add a message should the checkbox not be ticked. The checkbox is just a prerequisite of the accept button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to enable a button when the checkbox is checked, it can be easily done within the signal connection:

```
    self.ConfirmBox.toggled.connect(self.Acceptbtn.setEnabled)
```

`QWidget.setEnabled` requires a bool argument, which is the argument type passed on by the `toggled` signal, so the connection is very simple in this case.

---

Apart from this, there are some mistakes in your understanding of classes in Python: it seems like you are thinking in a "procedural" way, which doesn't work well with general PyQt implementations and common python usage, unless you really need some processing to be done when the class is created, for example to define some class attributes or manipulate the way some methods behave. But, even in this case, they will be *class* attributes, which will be inherited by **every** new instance.

The line `checked2 = confirm_box(self, state)` will obviously give you an error, since you are defining `checked2` as a class atribute. This means that its value will be processed and assigned when the class is being *created*: at this point, the instance of the class does not exist yet, Python just executes the code that is not part of the methods until it reaches the end of the class definition (its primary indentation). When it reaches the `checked2` line, it will try to call the `confirm_box` method, but the arguments `"self"` and `"state"` do not exist yet, as they have not been defined in the class attributes, hence the `NameError` exception.

Conceptually, what you have done is something similar to this:

```
    class SomeObject(object):
        print(something)
```

This wouldn't make any sense, since there is no "something" defined anywhere.

`self` is a python convention used for class methods: it is a keyword commonly used to refer to the instance of a class, you could actually use any valid python keyword at all.

The first argument of any class method is always the reference to the class instance, the only exceptions are `classmethod` and `staticmethod` decorators, but that's another story. When you call a method of an instanciated class, the instance object is automatically bound to the first argument of the called method: the `self` is the instance itself.

For example, you could create a class like this:

```
    class SomeObject(object):
        def __init__(Me):
            Me.someValue = 0

        def setSomeValue(Myself, value):
            Myself.someValue = value

        def multiplySomeValue(I, multi):
            I.setSomeValue(I.someValue * multi)
            return I.someValue
```

But that would be a bit confusing...

Comment: Very educational! Thank you. You've actually given me the answer to the new issue I was tackling with by your explanation of the variable within the class, makes a lot more sense now. Very much appreciated good sir/madam :)

Comment: The `stateChanged` signal does not send a boolean. Use the `toggled` signal.

Comment: Right, I always forget that. I'll correct the answer, thanks @ekhumoro